# Do series identities still hold for matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, power-series

The identity for geometric series
$$\sum_{k\geq0}q^k=\frac{1}{1-q}$$
for $|q|<1$ also holds for matrices provided that the largest eigenvalue has absolute value at most 1. Is it true that the identities
$$\sum_{k\geq0}kq^k=\frac{q}{(1-q)^2}\ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \sum_{k\geq0}k^2q^k=\frac{q(q+1)}{(1-q)^3}$$
which hold again for $|q|<1$ also hold in the matrix case (given some restriction on the largest eigenvalue)?

More generally, if we have some series identity
$$\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kq^k=f(q)$$
for some expression $f$, does it generalize to some set of matrices (assuming $f$ makes sense for matrices)? If the original identity holds on a disc of radius $r$, does the matrix identity always hold for matrices with maximal eigenvalue less than $r$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the spectral theorem?

Comment: In the matrix case, yes

Comment: So... I am out of practice here, but my basic recollection is that the answer to your question is "yes", in the case that your operator can be diagonalized (the spectral theorem helps you figure this out).  Convergence of the kinds of series you suggest is related to the spectral radius.  The [functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_calculus) is relevant.

Comment: Concerning the first formula: if the series $\sum kA^k$ is convergent then $(I-A)^2\sum kA^k=A.$ In general if $f(q)$ is represented by a MacLaurin series $\sum a_kq^k$ then $f(A)$ is defined by the series $\sum a_kA^k$ provided the series is convergent. The convergence of the series depends on the  eigenvalues of the matrix $A,$ more precisely on maximum of the absolute values of the eigenvalues. The matrix $A$ does not need to be diagonalizable,